# How do I remove an XML layer using Jaxb

Tags: jaxb

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<coordinate>
  <url>http://some-url</url>
  <properties>
    <property type="integer">key1=12345</property>
    <property visibility="private" type="string">key2=value2</property>
  </properties>
</coordinate>
```

I would like that to generate an Object structure that looks like this:

```
class Coordinate 
  string url
  List<Property> properties
class Property
  string type
  string visibility
```

Jaxb seems to require a "Properties" type layer in between the coordinate element and the property elements. Is there any way to just get it to add the properties directly to the list contained in the Coordinate object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation can be used for this scenario as below.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "properties")
@XmlElement(name="property")
protected List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<Property>();
```